# Are sbt `clean` and `compile` commands needed for `sbt test` and `sbt some_folder:dist`? And more questions

Tags: sbt

Our team is using sbt 0.13.15 with JDK 1.8 for one project that hasn't been touched since 2019. We just need to update it to be functional for a small upgrade (which is no longer a problem) and to not update it completely. The deployment process has been lackluster and doesn't follow our current process so that is what I'm working on. No one on our team uses scala nor sbt as the original developer left the team years ago. So I'm tackling this on my own. I have a few questions:

1. Anyway is there a difference between the compiling of `sbt compile` and `sbt test`?

From my understanding from this (see table of commands):
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project/

I used this too, but it is not as helpful:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running.html

`sbt test` will compile the code then run the tests. Is it basically doing `sbt compile test`? So there is no difference?

2. Likewise, is it necessary to use the `clean` command before another command, such as `sbt clean test`, if nothing was ran before?
3. Similarly, if I do `sbt some_folder:dist` to create a zip of my project, do I need to include the `clean` or `compile` command if there was nothing that was ran before that command? Will running `sbt some_folder:dist` compile the code then package to the specified target folder (I am assuming it is, but would like to make sure)?
4. Lastly, is there a difference in performance or time doing the commands separately (like `sbt clean compile test`) vs only one command (like `sbt test`)?
5. I was trying to do this:

```bash
timeout_duration=30m # in minutes
success_code=0
export SBT_OPTS="-Xms2024m -Xmx2024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

if timeout $timeout_duration sbt test; [ $? != $success_code ]; then
      echo -e "\n\n${RED}>> Tests for '${branch}' branch timed out after '${timeout_duration}' to prevent concourse from hanging."
      echo -e ">> Error code: $?${NO_COLOR}"
      exit $?
  fi
```

But it seems like it is downloading the plugins/dependencies but then hangs. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? We don't technically need it, but it is a nice to have.

When I run the `sbt test` command normally it works fine. Using the `timeout` wrapper command seems to be the issue. Even if I do it on a separate line before the IF block.

5. Is there anything else I should be aware of that is not obvious?

I have ran the commands in a docker container and tried to compared the times of the commands which were basically the same.